# How can I create a slope/hillsde tileset?

Tags: 2d, tilemap, tiles, pixel-art, tilesets

I struggle to create a 2D slope/hillside for a tileset. Not an impassable mountainside like in Pokemon, more a gentle slope which you can walk both directions. When you see the tilemap, one should get a feeling that the two sides of the slope have a different heigth.

Ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hello and welcome to gamedev.SE! Unfortunately, you can't ask for external resources here, so I modified the question to fit in the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sloped terrain is hard to do in a convincing way in an orthogonal 2d tilemap. But here is an example from the 1993 SNES game *Illusion of Gaia* by *Enix* which does a quite decent attempt:

[image: Slope]

This ramp uses 3 tiles:

[image: tiles]

What techniques are at use here?

- The diagonal cliff tiles provide a perspective hint
- The floor texture is darker than the one used for level ground. This creates a 3d illusion through shading. You could also use a brighter texture instead on the ramp in the opposite direction.
- Not visible on this screenshot, but the game mechanics also sell the ramp: When the player moves horizontally while on the ramp, it gets interpreted as diagonal movement. You can also increase the movement speed when moving downhill and decrease it when moving uphill.

Here is a more sophisticated example from a game with more technologically advanced pixel art. The original 1998 *Starcraft* by *Blizzard*:

[image: Starcraft Slope]

This slope is more detailed and it isn't tileable. But in the end it uses the exact same techniques: Diagonal rock formations and the shading of the floor texture (in this case lighter) create an illusion of perspective.

<sub>And by the way, you should not steal these tiles. Both companies still exist.</sub>

Comment: For those who might be confused at `Illusion of Gaia` it was called `illusion of Time` in europe. Awesome game btw.

Comment: Nice Answer with more examples than I could find, but I'm in need for a tiled one with a slope in all for directions and corners and stuff. I've already some new ideas that I will share as soon as they are somewhat ready.

Comment: @Gistiv Have you considered using a 3d engine for your terrain?